# Get instance objects which are not on first frame

Tags: actionscript-3, instance

I'm using actionscript 3.0 and Flash Professional CS5.5
I ran into a problem with instance objects which are not on the first frame.
My first frame is a menu and my second frame contains a TLF text field.
I have given the text field an instance name, let's say "username_txt".
Now if I turn off the "Automatically Declare Stage Instances" and do this in my main class

```
 public class MainClass extends MovieClip {

        public var username_txt:TLFTextField;

        public function MainClass() {
            username_txt.text = "anything";
        }
 }
```

I will receive a run time error stating that I try to access the property of a null object. (I have import all the necessary classes so that is not the problem)

This does not happen when I put the text right in the first frame though.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the text field has not yet been instantiated since the frame has not yet been reached, I'm unsure there is an elegant way to perform this task.

Perhaps a better model would be to decouple your data model from your views.

Create a singleton class to store data:

```
package
{

    public class ApplicationModel
    {

        /** Singleton instance. */
        private static var instance:ApplicationModel = new ApplicationModel();

        /** Return singleton instance. */
        public static function getInstance():ApplicationModel
        {
            return instance;
        }

        /** Data Model */
        public var username:String;

        /** Constructor as singleton enforcer */
        public function ApplicationModel()
        {
            if (instance)
                throw new Error("ApplicationModel is a singleton and can only be accessed through ApplicationModel.getInstance()");
        }

    }
}
```

Then from within anywhere such as keyframes or classes, you can get the instance of the object, implemented either as:

```
ApplicationModel.getInstance().username = "test";
```

Or a better practice would be:

```
var applicationModel:ApplicationModel = ApplicationModel.getInstance();
applicationModel.username = "test";
```

As per your example:

```
public class MainClass extends MovieClip {

    public var username_txt:TLFTextField;

    public function MainClass() {
        ApplicationModel.getInstance().username = "anything";
    }
}
```

Then, on the frame you need to update your TLFTextField (frame script of frame 2), you set the text based upon the model:

```
username_txt.text = ApplicationModel.getInstance().username
```

Your view will always update when needed.

Comment: Wow! I am looking into it. Do you mean that designers and programmers have to handle the problem like this in every application since I doubt not many application run on one frame?

Comment: These patterns help designers and programmers work together, for sure.  Also, you're asking a great question about timeline development.  Application life cycles can quickly become complex and onerous.  Especially binding data to views becomes easier and more clear when you can separate data in to a model.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I try to embrace this even though I'm still not quite used to it yet.

Comment: "since I doubt not many application run on one frame?" Most maintainable applications will not have any content at all on timeline frames, since it quickly becomes problematic. You might want to take a look at a MVC framework like robotlegs (http://www.robotlegs.org/)

Comment: Learning never ceases to amaze me. Thanks a lot guys